# Use a proxy with Terraform

Tags: proxy, terraform

I am unable to use our corporate proxy with Terraform. I configured the following environment variables (I'm under Windows 7):

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.company.local:8080
set HTTP_USER=userID
set HTTP_PASSWORD=password
```

But when launching Terraform init, I get the following error:

> Error installing provider "azurerm":  `Get https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform-provider-azurerm/`: Proxy Authentication Required.

I can't find any documentation on how to configure our troubleshoot a proxy with Terraform. Any thoughts ?

Thanks :)

Comment: On Linux typically I  need to also set corresponding httpS_proxy environment variables for accessing https URL's via a proxy server i.e `set HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy.company.local:8080` etc.

Comment: I use Terraform through a proxy most of the time, setting just the two `HTTP_PROXY=http://<username>:<password>@<proxy>:<port>/` and `HTTPS_PROXY=http://<username>:<password>@<proxy>:<port>/` variables works for me.

Answer (score 4):

Terraform sends all requests via HTTPS. You have to configure a HTTPS Proxy as well, as in `set HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.company.local:8443`.

Comment: The OP seems to have a problem with proxy authenication, not with setting a proxy at all. The comment by @bodgit seems to address that.

Comment: `HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.company.local:8443` should be `HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy.company.local:8443`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to set the Terrafrom proxy with password setting, create the following environment variables in windows

```
HTTP_PROXY=http://<username>:<password>@<proxy>:<port>
HTTPS_PROXY=http://<username>:<password>@<proxy>:<port>
```

Note: HTTPS_PROXY (**HTTPS_PROXY**=**http**://username:password@proxy:port)also set the same http url not https